# How to get access to module-local property files in a WAR application?

Tags: java, web-applications, resources, classpath, war

I have the following structure of web application:

```
WAR
  - ...
  - WEB-INF
    - lib
       - module1.jar
          - messages.properties
          - MyClassModule1.class
       - module2.jar
          - messages.properties
          - MyClassModule2.class
    - classes
       - messages.properties
       - MyClass.class
```

I want the classes inside the modules to access the `messages.properties` local to their corresponding module, e.g. I want the `MyClassModule1` to access the `messages.properties` inside `WEB-INF/lib/module1.jar`, and not the one in `WEB-INF/classes` as it seems to happen right now.

The methods I have tested are the following:

```
MyClassModule1.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("messages.properties");
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("messages.properties");
```

Both of them give me the `WEB-INF/classes/messages.properties`, not the `WEB-INF/lib/module1.jar!/messages.properties`.

Is there a *non-triky* way to get the local `messages.properties` when I call the previous `getResourceAsStream(...)` methods from inside the module?

Some constraints to take into account:

- the property files must have *all the same name*
- they must be placed at the root of the `*.jar` file or at the root of the
  `WEB-INF/classes/` WAR file, as in the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try 
    {
   props.load(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/someProps.properties"));    
} catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    someProperty = props.getProperty("someKey");
}
```

It works in Eclipse because when launching an application, the system classloader is configured with your jar as part of its classpath. (E.g. java -jar my.jar will load my.jar in the system class loader.) This is not the case with web applications - application servers use complex class loading to isolate webapplications from each other and from the internals of the application server. For example, see the tomcat classloader how-to, and the diagram of the classloader hierarchy used.